# Flattening a list of Maybe elements from Just [[x1],[x2]] to Just [x1,x2]

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a function I'm supposed to define like so:

```
func :: (a -> Maybe [b]) -> [a] -> Maybe [b]
```

Some examples of how it's supposed to work :

```
func (\x -> if x == 0 then Nothing else Just [x]) [1,2]
```

Should result in:

> Just [1,2]

Another example:

```
func (\x -> if x == 0 then Nothing else Just [x]) [1,0]
```

> Nothing

If anything in the list is a `Nothing`, then the function returns `Nothing`. Otherwise if all the elements in the list return a `Just [x]` then it's supposed to return a list like: `Just [x1, x2, ...]`.

I tried using `fmap` for similar calls to the above which returns something like:

> [Just [1], Just [2], ...]

If I use `sequence` on the list `fmap` returns, it'll follow the rules of the above (returning a `Nothing` if anything in the list is a `Nothing`), which is great. Except it returns a list like this:

> Just [[1],[2]]

which is not the format I need. In that case I would need it to be:

> Just [1,2]

As I just started learning Haskell and monads are still a fresh topic to me, I'm having some trouble figuring how to format this list or if there's a better way of solving this problem. I cannot change the function type signature.

Comment: How would you flatten a list, without a `Maybe` present?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To turn a list like `[[1],[2]]`, into `[1,2]`, use [`concat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat). In your case, since the list is inside a `Maybe`, you'll need to call `fmap concat` on it.

Also, note that any time you call `sequence` (or `sequenceA`) on the result of `map`, `fmap`, or `<$>`, you can save a function by combining both into `mapM` (or `traverse`).